# How can a single reference variable access to all object fields?

Tags: java, jvm

```
Animal myAnimal = new Animal();
```

I have this code above. As far as I know, it will do these things :

1. An animal object will be created on heap memory
2. The reference to that object will be passed to the reference variable "myAnimal"
   In other words, "myAnimal" variable holds the memory address of "Animal" object on heap.

What I don't understand is that

1. How does the memory address value look like?
2. Is that one address or numerous address value? If only one, how can myAnimal have accesses to all object fields of Animal object like myAnimal.name, myAnimal.height,...?

Can anyone explain this please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java Virtual Machine Specification [states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.4)

> There are three kinds of reference types: class types, array types,
>   and interface types. **Their values are references** to dynamically
>   created class instances, arrays, or class instances or arrays that
>   implement interfaces, respectively.

and [clarifies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.2)

> Values of type *reference* can be thought of **as pointers to objects**.

So the variable `myAnimal` in

```
Animal myAnimal = new Animal();
```

is storing a pointer to the `Animal` object on the heap.

You ask

> How does the memory address value look like?

A memory address is typically just a numerical value that's an offset into the process' allocated memory. When a process reads that value, it can directly address that location and read from or write to it (think of it as an offset index in an array).

The object itself is more than just its address. In fact, its address can change multiple times over the lifetime of the JVM process as the garbage collector moves objects around.

However, the [JVMS does not specify](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.7) the internal structure of an object.

> The Java Virtual Machine does not mandate any particular internal
>   structure for objects.
>
> *In some of Oracle’s implementations of the Java Virtual Machine, a
>   reference to a class instance is a pointer to a handle that is itself
>   a pair of pointers: one to a table containing the methods of the
>   object and a pointer to the Class object that represents the type of
>   the object, and the other to the memory allocated from the heap for
>   the object data.*

This doesn't help greatly, but we can assume that the memory allocated for the object data has to be large enough to contain all the object's fields and the data needs to be accessible quickly, ie. in constant time, as opposed to proportionally to the amount of data. The typical solution is to again use offsets. Take this class for example

```
class Animal {
    private String name;
    private byte height;
}
```

The field `name` is of type `String`, a reference type, which we know essentially just stores a pointer. If we assume our JVM only needs 32 bits to store a pointer, we know we only need 32 bits for this field.

The field `height` is of type `byte`, which is specified to only need 8 bits.

So each `Person` object really only needs `32+8` bits, 5 bytes for its data. The JVM will most likely allocate more than that for its internal organization, but let's simplify to just those 5 bytes. In your example, the JVM will allocate the first 4 bytes for the `name` and the next byte for the `age`. Something like

```
 0        8       16       24       32       40
 +--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
 |               name                | height |
```

You ask

> Is that one address or numerous address value? If only one, how can
>   myAnimal have accesses to all object fields of Animal object like
>   myAnimal.name, myAnimal.height,...?

`myAnimal` holds only one address, but an expression like

```
myAnimal.height
```

can be thought of as reading 1 byte (because we know `height` is of type byte) from memory at the address determined by adding 4 (because the location of the data for `height` is offset by the 4 bytes needed for `name`) to the value stored in `myAnimal`.

Consider `myAnimal` storing a pointer to a memory address of `12`, initialized with a `name` pointing to a String at memory address `1345` and a `height` value of 6. In memory, that could look like

```
                   myAnimal
                      |
                      v
Heap:             ...12.......13.......14.......15.......16.......17
Object offsets:   ....0        1        2        3        4        5
                  ....+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+ 
                      |               1345                |    6   |
```

To read `myAnimal.height`, the JVM would calculate `12 + 4 = 16` and read the byte (`6`) at that offset. To assign a new value to `myAnimal.name`, the JVM would calculate `12 + 0`, and write 4 bytes representing some the new pointer value, overwriting the `1345`.

Comment: Thank you very much. This also answered how a reference variable can access methods and static variables. I didn't know it goes to another "handle"! And that "handle" itself is a pair of pointers! Also, as you said, that another pointers also contains offsets to each object field data (I'm not sure I understood this right or not). That's a lot of information!

Comment: @Bonsaisteak note that “*some of Oracle’s implementations*” actually means “*very ancient implementations from Sun*”, as this “pair of pointers” concept is not used in the implementations of the last decade(s). • The field offsets are usually assigned at class loading time. Since it is known that the expression `myAnimal.height` accesses the field `height` declared by the class `Animal`, the actual field offset can be looked up at the runtime metadata of the class, without the need for an actual object. In most implementations, offsets never change, so this is done only once.

Comment: @Holger Thanks a lot! That's what I was still confused about. I will research more about this "runtime metadata". In JVM, it seems to be stored in "method area".

Answer (score 6):

This is an oversimplification:

1. It's just a number that represents some address location; how big that number is depends on your computer's architecture (32 bit or 64 bit)
2. It is one address value; it is the address location of the place where your object representation in memory **starts**.

You can compare it with the address of your house. It has one address. All rooms in your house (fields) have a different location, but you have to enter through your front door (the 'start' location). Room locations are relative to your front door. I admit this example is a bit contrived, but you get the point...

Answer (score 2):

Addresses are just `long` numbers to denote the memory location of your object. And they depends on the bit's of the machine. It is 64 bit long on 64 bit machine and 32 bit long on 32 bit machine.

> How does the memory address value look like?

If you are really enthusiastic to see those big numbers in your console, you can actually explore the [Unsafe API](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/misc/Unsafe.html)

```
public native long getAddress(long address)
```

> Fetches a native pointer from a given memory address.  If the address is
>   zero, or does not point into a block obtained from #allocateMemory , the results are undefined.
>
> If the native pointer is less than 64 bits wide, it is extended as
>   an unsigned number to a Java long.  The pointer may be indexed by any
>   given byte offset, simply by adding that offset (as a simple integer) to
>   the long representing the pointer.  The number of bytes actually read
>   from the target address maybe determined by consulting #addressSize .

---

> Is that one address or numerous address value? If only one, how can myAnimal have accesses to all object fields of Animal object like myAnimal.name, myAnimal.height,...?

Well it should be **one** on top level and that address location may contain address locations of others (I am not really sure)

I have not really tried running this on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

When an object is created, java does not share its `Actual Memory Address` with refrence variables instead of that Java creates an `index number` for your `object`,which is passed to the `reference variable` of that object. So, you are able to access your object with help of that `index number`. Further your object hold the `refrences` of  its `children` and help you to access them.